Using celery-beat as a timer
In my application, I want to run some function once after a certain time interval since the object is created. Is django-celery-beat the right tool for doing this?

Yes, celery beat is the way to go for scheduling background tasks.

Yes, Celery Beat is good for background tasks. However, sometimes integrating Celery into our project is a bit difficult. If you have a small task for the background process, I recommend using django-rq.
here is the official link for your reference:
https://pypi.org/project/django-rq/0.2.1/
